# nutiteq map: Strange map touch behaves in ScrollView container

Tags: android, android-maps

I'm using [nutiteq](https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d) map. I have made a sample app using this map and it works all right.

But when I put map into ScrollView container then it behaves a strange way like when I touch map for navigate, it is unexpectedly zoom out and zoom in and all that.
It is only happen when I put map into scrollview container. In another view it works all right.
I want to use it with scrollview container but I can't because of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView has some special touch events and states (like Cancel touch) which were not handled in earlier versions, but are handled if you take the latest version.

Another issue of ScrollView what you may get is that scrolling is canceled after some panning, as View/Layout controller thinks that user wants to scroll whole view, so MapView does not get necessary events, it just gets Touch cancel. Maybe this can be resolved with Android view parameters.